# Master-Detail datagrids binded to dbcontext/dataset not filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, dbcontext

im new to c# and wpf...
trying to make simple wpf master-detail application with binding to localdb
the first grid is working properly but the other one is not showing data/not filtered to only show details (depends on what im using)...

im using entity framework code-first

Cars is the master and freights are the details

I tried binding to context and also binding to dataset/dataadapter
FK_Freights_Cars_CarID is the EXACT name of the FK in the DATASET scheme

I tried every single available way but not even one is working
default drag and drop from data source give me error on movetofirst because of epmty items

BTW i prefer using context way...

For Both Ways:

xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Src:TGTDataSet x:Key="tGTDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="carsViewSource" Source="{Binding Cars, 
       Source={StaticResource tGTDataSet}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="carsFreightsViewSource" Source="{Binding 
       Path=FK_Freights_Cars_CarID, Source={StaticResource 
         carsViewSource}}" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

default xaml generated from drag and drop from data source:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Src:TGTDataSet x:Key="tGTDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="carsViewSource" Source="{Binding Cars, 
       Source={StaticResource tGTDataSet}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="carsFreightsViewSource" Source="{Binding 
       Path=Cars_CarID, Source={StaticResource 
         carsViewSource}}" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

code:

```
...
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows.Data;
using TGT_2.Src;
using TGT_2.Src.TGTDataSetTableAdapters;
...

public partial class CarsWindow : Window
{
    private tgtEntityDataModel context = new tgtEntityDataModel();
    private CollectionViewSource carsViewSource;
    private CollectionViewSource carsFreightsViewSource;
    public CarsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        carsViewSource = 
          (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("carsViewSource");
        carsFreightsViewSource = 
          (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("carsFreightsViewSource");
        DataContext = this;
    }
...
```

for context:

```
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        context.Cars.Load();
        context.Freights.Load();

        carsViewSource.Source = context.Cars.Local;
        carsFreightsViewSource.Source = context.Freights.Local;

        carsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        carsFreightsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        ...
```

for dataset/dataadapter:

```
    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TGTDataSet tGTDataSet = (TGTDataSet)FindResource("tGTDataSet");

        CarsTableAdapter tGTDataSetCarsTableAdapter = new CarsTableAdapter();
        FreightsTableAdapter tGTDataSetFreightsTableAdapter = new FreightsTableAdapter();

        tGTDataSetCarsTableAdapter.Fill(tGTDataSet.Cars);
        tGTDataSetFreightsTableAdapter.Fill(tGTDataSet.Freights);

        carsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        carsFreightsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        ...
```

the details grid is not showing data/not filtered to only show details (depends on what im using)...
And THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way for the existing approaches, but I just reconstructed everything by making Data Source bind to Object, not to database directly.

[image: Data Source Configuration Wizard]